# React PropTypes defaultProps doesnt work, when "null" is passed

Tags: reactjs

I have a case where I pass multiple properties to a component. The props come from wordpress, so I can't influence what exactly is passed - the values always come up with "null".

However, I would like that when "null" is passed, the defaultProp value is taken.

I need to solve this somehow via the component itself.... is there a way?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/proptypes-in-react-forked-g29oy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

**The default props is used only when you not marking props as required**

[Here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md) is also an eslint rule for that

When you mark it as required, you are sure that the props will be passed, so there will be no reason to have `defaultProps`

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  firstName: PropTypes.string,
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  firstName: "John Doe"
};
```

**OR**

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Also, when you are passing props as null, meaning that the prop's variable is not referenced to any actual value, which is equivalent to not passing it.

Comment: Okay sure it shouldn't be as required, I changed that, but it still won't get the default value. I updated the Codesandbox Link

Answer (score 0):

You should use `or` with `undefined` behind. it make sure we don't pass `null` value to the component. It uses `undefined` instead and `defaultProps` will work

```
<MyComponent firstName={firstName || undefined} />
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/proptypes-in-react-forked-g29oy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Yeah that seems a nice solution, but i pass the props like that: ```<TextElement {...element} />``` is that anyway possible with the spread operator?

Comment: Just add `firstName` behind: `<TextElement {...element} firstName={element.firstName || undefined} />`

Comment: The problem is, that all my props are in ...element from wordpress, they are dynamic